# Monte Carlo simulation of classical Heisenberg model doesn't represent Curie curve

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, statistics

I've created a JavaScript file to execute and log average energy and magnetization values of 2D lattice classical Heisenberg model.

I run the simulation with parameters,

- `L=32` (Number of atomic spins on each side of the lattice)
- `N=L*L` (total number of spins)
- `J=1` (exchange constant)
- `T=0, 0.25, ..., 4.75, 5.00` (temperature values ranging from 0 to 5 with 0.25 steps)
- `k_B = 1.380649e-23` (Boltzmann constant, **i'm not sure if I should use Boltzmann constant or not**)
- `maxSteps=1000*N` (maximum Monte Carlo steps per each temperature value, in this case 1,024,000 steps)

---

#### Question #1:

When I run the simuation with the code below I get random looking average magnetization values which doesn't look any similar to Curie curve where Average Magnetization approaches to 0 as temperate increases.
[image: Curie curve]
The sample values I got from runnig my code:

```
0.00 - 112.3611554761474,  0.25 - 23.5203320525913,
0.50 - 53.703480153558935, 0.75 - 92.0844269044712,
1.00 - 125.14550180873817, 1.25 - 74.21278454080122,
1.50 - 71.35901940700411,  1.75 - 34.8608142613192,
2.00 - 31.958062690297456, 2.25 - 87.57994096782724,
2.50 - 72.47576840153171,  2.75 - 68.64552406668619,
3.00 - 150.81073588464645, 3.25 - 124.51410153666252,
3.50 - 54.3372397486911,   3.75 - 20.10328424666724,
4.00 - 42.026588080636444, 4.25 - 52.42965924964965,
4.50 - 76.06067331506105,  4.75 - 17.969373459157673,
5.00 - 30.795866110306843
```

Why might this be happening? I tried to run simulation for larger lattice (100x100 with 10,000,000 steps per each temperature value and temperatures ranging from 0 to 100 with 1 steps but got the similar results)

#### Question #2:

I previously run Ising model and got the same results for average magnetization-temperature graph with random scattering of points representing $M(T)-T$ values. I used the Boltzmann distribution to calculate the acceptance probability to decide whether or not to accept the spin flip (`Math.random() < Math.exp(-dE/(k_B*T))`). I found another way to calculate the acceptance probabilities in a book related to this subject and it was using the following function to calculate it:

```javascript
// Transition probability calcualtion
function transitionProbability(t, neighboringSpins) {
    t=(t+1)/4;
    let e4 = Math.exp(-4/t);
    let e8 = Math.pow(e4, 2);
    let c = 0;

    if(neighboringSpins == 0) {
        c = 0;
    }
    if(neighboringSpins == 2) {
        c = e4;
    }
    if(neighboringSpins == 4) {
        c = e8;
    }
    if(neighboringSpins == -2) {
        c = 1/e4;
    }
    if(neighboringSpins == -4) {
        c = 1/e8;
    }

    return c;
}
```

In this code variable  `neighboringSpins` represents the summed spin value of neighbors of the spin to be flipped which may be -4, -2, 0, 2, 4 since the spins may have -1 or +1 values ($\sigma_i=\{+1, -1\}$). And this function calculates the acceptance probability for each of these cases rather than using Boltzmann  distribution. When I used this function to calculate acceptance probabilities the results for $M(T)-T$ plot was similar to Curie curve. But classical Heisenberg model, by definition, doesn't have spins with exact values like +1 or -1, rather the spins are unit vectors with random directions in 3D space ($\vec{\sigma}_i\in R^3, |\vec{\sigma}_i|=1$). So why do I not get the same results for using Boltzmann distribution and mentioned acceptance probability calculation function? Why do I get better results with the mentioned function? What can I do to get similar results for classical Heisenberg model's Monte Carlo simulation which it's code given below?

The code for simulation:

```javascript
var L = 32;
var N = L*L;
var J = 1;
var T = 0;
const k_B = 1.380649e-23;

var system = Array.from(new Array(L), () => new Array(L));
var energyValues = new Array();
var magnetizationValues = new Array();

var maxSteps = 1000*N;
var stepsCounter = 0;

// Vector operations
function dotProduct(vectorA, vectorB) {
    return (vectorA[0]*vectorB[0])+(vectorA[1]*vectorB[1])+(vectorA[2]*vectorB[2]);
};

function addVectors(...vectors) {
    return vectors.reduce(
        (resultVector, vectorToAdd) => [
            resultVector[0]+vectorToAdd[0],
            resultVector[1]+vectorToAdd[1],
            resultVector[2]+vectorToAdd[2]
        ],
        [0, 0, 0]
    );
};

function flipVector(vector) {
    return vector.map(
        component => -component
    );
};

function magnitude(vector) {
    return Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(vector[0], 2)
        +Math.pow(vector[1], 2)
        +Math.pow(vector[2], 2)
    );
};

// Initialize 2D lattice with random spins with magnitude of 1 unit
function initializeSystem() {
    for(let i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < L; j++) {
            let theta = Math.random()*(2*Math.PI);
            let phi = Math.acos(2*Math.random()-1);

            system[i][j] = [
                Math.sin(theta)*Math.cos(phi),
                Math.sin(theta)*Math.sin(phi),
                Math.cos(theta)
            ];
        }
    }

    // Calculate initial energy and magnetization
    let { energy, magnetization } = calculateEnergyAndMagnetization();

    energyValues.push(energy);
    magnetizationValues.push(magnetization);
};

function calculateEnergyAndMagnetization() {
    let energy = 0;
    let magnetization = [0, 0, 0];

    for(let i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < L; j++) {
            energy += -J*dotProduct(system[i][j], addVectors(system[(i-1+L)%L][j], system[i][(j+1)%L]));
            magnetization = addVectors(magnetization, system[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return {
        energy,
        magnetization
    };
};

function monteCarloStep() {
    let i = parseInt(L*Math.random());
    let j = parseInt(L*Math.random());

    let neighboringSpins = addVectors(
        system[(i-1+L)%L][j],
        system[i][(j+1)%L],
        system[(i+1)%L][j],
        system[i][(j-1+L)%L]
    );
    let dE = 2*J*dotProduct(system[i][j], neighboringSpins);
    let dM = flipVector(system[i][j]).map(component => 2*component);

    if(dE <= 0) {
        system[i][j] = flipVector(system[i][j]);
        energyValues.push(energyValues[stepsCounter]+dE);
        magnetizationValues.push(addVectors(magnetizationValues[stepsCounter], dM));
    } else {
        if(Math.random() < Math.exp(-dE/(k_B*T))) {
            system[i][j] = flipVector(system[i][j]);
            energyValues.push(energyValues[stepsCounter]+dE);
            magnetizationValues.push(addVectors(magnetizationValues[stepsCounter], dM));
        } else {
            energyValues.push(energyValues[stepsCounter]);
            magnetizationValues.push(magnetizationValues[stepsCounter]);
        }
    }
    stepsCounter++;
};

for(let t = 0; t < 21; t++) {
    T = t/4;
    stepsCounter = 0;
    energyValues = new Array();
    magnetizationValues = new Array();
    initializeSystem();

    while(stepsCounter < maxSteps) {
        monteCarloStep();
    }
    
    let avgEnergy = energyValues.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0)/maxSteps;
    let avgMagnetization = magnetizationValues
        .reduce((sum, value) => addVectors(sum, value), [0, 0, 0])
        .map(component => component/maxSteps);
    
    console.log(`Temperature: ${T}`);
    console.log(`Average Energy: ${avgEnergy}`);
    console.log(`Average Magnetization: ${magnitude(avgMagnetization)}`);
}
```